# ExtJS4, how to get the only "last" panel when click on nested panels?

Tags: javascript, extjs, click, panel

Using ExtJS 4.2 and nested panels, when I click on a panel I need to get **this only panel**.
But I currently get this panel AND its parents panels.

[Here's the FIDDLE.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k3s)
When you click on "A > B > C", the function must be called only one time, with "A > B > C" panel as parameter.
When you click on "A > B", the function must be called only one time, with "A > B" panel as parameter.
etc.

I'm not supposed to know that top level panel is the top level panel.
There is not only once click, the code have to work with multiple clicks on any panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `click` event with `event` param and stop it just after calling `myFonction`.

**Code snippet:**

```
panel.on('click', function (event) {
    myFonction(panel);
    event.stopEvent();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}, this, {
    element: 'el'
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k4a)**

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you ! I only use the "event.stopEvent();" and it's fine.
Are the others instructions really required ?